# Stripe Payment Using VSCode and XCode issue

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Hi every one I am trying to build E-Commerce IOS app ,  and I am using Stripe payment gateway with VSCode

but when I run this line of code : paymentContext.requestPayment()

it gives me this error : Error: Must provide source or customer

here is my Checkout view controller

```
class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController, CartItemDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var selectPaymentMethodBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var selectShippingMethod: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var serviceFeeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var delivaryFeeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtotalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var paymentContext : STPPaymentContext!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setupTableView()
    setupPaymentInfo()
    setupStripeConfig()
    
    
}


func setupTableView(){
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellIdentifiers.CartItemCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifiers.CartItemCell)

}

func setupPaymentInfo(){
    serviceFeeLabel.text = StripeCart.proccessingFees.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
    delivaryFeeLabel.text = StripeCart.shippingFees.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
    subtotalLabel.text = StripeCart.subtotal.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
    totalLabel.text = StripeCart.total.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
}


func setupStripeConfig(){
    
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
    //config.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.name ,.phoneNumber]
    
    let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
    
    paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
    
    paymentContext.delegate = self
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    
    
    
}

@IBAction func selectPaymentMethodClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
}

@IBAction func selectShippingMethodClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    paymentContext.pushShippingViewController()
}



func removeItem(product: Product) {
    StripeCart.removeItemFromCart(item: product)
    tableView.reloadData()
    setupPaymentInfo()
    paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
}


@IBAction func placeOrderClicked(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
    
    paymentContext.requestPayment()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    
}
```

}

and here is my STPPaymentContextDelegate code

```
extension CheckoutViewController : STPPaymentContextDelegate {
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    
    if let paymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption {
        selectPaymentMethodBtn.setTitle(paymentMethod.label, for: .normal)
    } else {
        selectPaymentMethodBtn.setTitle("Select Method", for: .normal)
    }
    

    
}




func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action in
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default) { action in
        self.paymentContext.retryLoading()
    }
    
    
}




func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
    
    let idempotency = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    let data : [String : Any] = [
    
        "total" : StripeCart.total ,
        "customerID" : UserService.user.stripID ,
        "idempotency" : idempotency
        
    ]
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("makeCharge").call(data) { result, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(STPPaymentStatus.error , error)
            return
        }
        StripeCart.clearCart()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.setupPaymentInfo()
        completion(STPPaymentStatus.success, nil)
    }
    
   

}




func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    
    let title : String
    let msg : String
    switch status {
    case .success:
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        title = "SUCCESS"
        msg = "THX FOR YOUR SHOPPING"
    case .error:
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        title = "ERROR"
        msg = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
    case .userCancellation:
        return
    }
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true , completion: nil)
    
}
```

}

and here is my index.js code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
```

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp()

const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_test_key)

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.firestore.document('users/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

```
const data = snap.data();
const email = data.email;

const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: email })



return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({ stripID: customer.id })
```

});

exports.makeCharge = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

```
const customerID = data.customer_id;
const total = data.total;
const idempotency = data.idempotency;
const uid = context.auth.uid;

if (uid === null) {
    console.log('Illegal Access')
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied' , 'Illegal access attempt')
}

return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: 'JOD',
    customer: customerID
}, {
    idempotency_key: idempotency
}).then( _ => {
    return
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal' , err + 'Ln tutemm alsheraa')
});
```

})

exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

```
const customerID = data.customer_id;
const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
const uid = context.auth.uid;

if (uid === null) {
    console.log('Illegal Access')
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied' , 'Illegal access attempt')
}

return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customerID} , 
    {stripe_version: stripeVersion}
    ).then((key) => {
        return key
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal' , 'unable to create ephemeral key')
    })
```

})

so how could I solve this problem

Note : I am Living in Jordan , I don't know why I told you that but I think it makes different

I found that the problem is inside stripe.charges.create({ ... }) code , thats why when I printed the customerID with error it gives me (.undefined) , and thats why when I check my stripe Logs for charge event I found this

[My Charge Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch19N.png)

but where is the problem exactly  ???

I tried to add my real visa but it showed me error says : Your card was declined

I tried to add the customerID manually hardcoded into my index.js but it shows me this error : "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card"

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Must provide source or customer` means that you're trying to create a charge but either the source(card) is missing from the request or a customer ID that has a saved payment method in order for the charge to work.

The client-side code you've provided looks fine but would recommend checking your Stripe logs (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) to validate that if you're adding in a new source then the request to attach the source to customer object isn't failing.

I'm pretty certain that the error is coming from `stripe.charges.create({ ... })`. You'd want to check if the `customerID` is indeed present and if it is, does that customer have a source attached.